# Using SQL to ignore all employees without certain deduction code

Tags: sql

I am trying to pull a report from a database using SQL.  All of my employees have multiple deduction codes, I want to ignore all deductions on any employee that has a certain deduction.  i.e. I only want to pull employees that do not have a 33.  Of course, I can pull everything that is not a 33 but then I get the other deductions for employees that have a 33.

```
----------
WHERE 
  (
    (
      (
        Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Employee NOT IN (
          SELECT 
            Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Employee 
          Where 
            Viewpoint.dbo.PRDT.EDLCode = 33
        )
      )
```

Comment: And can you show code wise what you did?? Or do we have to guess that?

Comment: Yeah, we need more information.  If you could create an SQL fiddle with relevant parts of the schema and some example information, you'd probably get an answer pretty fast, but as it is the only answer I could offer would be based on a made up schema and probably wouldn't even help

Comment: I tried this:   Where  Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Employee NOT EXISTS (SELECT  Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Employee Where  Viewpoint.dbo.PRDT.EDLCode  = 33)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one generic approach to excluding employees that have deduction 33.

```
WHERE empId NOT IN (SELECT empId from myTable WHERE deductionId = 33)
```

This approach excludes by the employee identifier for any employee that has a deduction 33.  Of course, since you haven't posted your SQL, this approach will need to be modified to suit your specific scenario.

**UPDATE**

Based on the new information added to the question, here is a more specific answer:

```
WHERE Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Employee NOT IN (SELECT prdt.Employee FROM Viewpoint.dbo.PRDT prdt WHERE prdt.EDLCode = 33)
AND Viewpoint.dbo.PRDT.PREndDate &SPARM01 --what is this?  are you missing an equals sign?
AND Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.ActiveYN ='Y' 
AND Viewpoint.dbo.PRDT.PRCo ='1' 
ORDER BY Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.LastName, Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.FirstName
```

NOTES

- the stuff that follows the `NOT IN` is a [subquery](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx), and so it needs to follow the basic SELECT FROM WHERE pattern.
- since you only have AND conditions (no OR conditions) in your WHERE clause, there's no need to have all of those parentheses.  You only need parentheses around the subquery.
- i've added a comment to one part of your WHERE condition that appears to be missing an equals sign.

Comment: I had originally had:   Where  Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Employee NOT EXISTS (SELECT  Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Employee Where  Viewpoint.dbo.PRDT.EDLCode  = 33)  I changed 'Exists' to 'IN' based on your suggestion but I am just getting an error

Comment: and the error is ???  also, can you confirm if this is mysql, ms msql, oracle, or something else?

Comment: The error I get is 'There is an error in the SQL Statement, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Where'. Incorrect syntax near')'.  Its definitely SQL...

Comment: can you please post your entire query ?  And tell me what type of database you're using?

Comment: SELECT  Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Employee AS 'Employee', Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.LastName AS 'LastName', Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.FirstName AS 'FirstName', Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Sex AS 'Sex', Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.SSN AS 'SSN', Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.BirthDate AS 'BirthDate', Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.HireDate AS 'HireDate', Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Craft AS 'Craft', Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Class AS 'Class', Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Address AS 'Address', Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.City AS 'City', Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.State AS 'State', Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Zip AS 'Zip', Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.HrlyRate AS 'HrlyRate', Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.SalaryAmt AS 'SalaryAmt'

Comment: Viewpoint.dbo.PRDT.EDLCode AS 'EDLCode', Viewpoint.dbo.PRDT.PRCo AS 'PRCo'
FROM ((Viewpoint.dbo.PRDT INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.PREH ON (Viewpoint.dbo.PRDT.Employee=Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Employee) AND (Viewpoint.dbo.PRDT.PRCo=Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.PRCo)))
WHERE ( ((Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Employee =Where  Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Employee NOT EXISTS (SELECT  Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Employee Where  Viewpoint.dbo.PRDT.EDLCode  = 33)) AND (Viewpoint.dbo.PRDT.PREndDate &SPARM01) AND (Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.ActiveYN ='Y') AND (Viewpoint.dbo.PRDT.PRCo ='1') ) ) ORDER BY Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.LastName, Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.FirstName

Comment: Looking at it when I posted it, I saw some glaring issues.  I changed the WHERE statement to WHERE ( ((Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Employee NOT IN (SELECT  Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Employee Where  Viewpoint.dbo.PRDT.EDLCode  = 33))  Now it pulls data but it gives me all employees with all deduction codes, it is back to not ignoring employee IDs that have 33.  I get every employee and every deduction code except 33

Comment: the query you posted in the comments doesn't have valid syntax (example:  `WHERE ( ((Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Employee =Where Viewpoint.dbo.PREH.Employee NOT EXISTS` ).  Can you update your original question with the query that's working, but not giving you the right results?